# epubjs-rn - Highlight a text in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, epub.js

I am new to RN and to epubjs and I need some help on the best way to solve the highlighting a text. As far as I understand, once the user highlights a text, iOS shows it default "copy, define, share.." buttons.

How do I disable that? Or is it possible to add a highlight option to the set of default options and get a callback with the text range once the highlight is done?

Help would be really appreciated.